# How do I scp files with names matching a "greater than" rule?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, scp

I've got a data pipeline that fetches files (through SCP) from a remote server every 5 minutes. For that, I'm using [scp.py](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py), but I'm also open to pure shell commands suggestions.

The file names are in the following pattern: `XXXX<date>.xxx` where date is in the format `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`. Unfortunately, the `date` is not regular (the time delta between files is not the same), so it can be anything.

What I needed is a way of copying remote files that matches the rule "greater than `some_date`" (i.e. greater than 20220907191511).

Is it possible? I've tried a greater than symbol (`>`) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to do a few things.

Firstly you need to extract the `<date>` part from each filename. This could be using a regex or, if possible by slicing the string.

eg..

```
from datetime import datetime

file_name = "myfile20221010163900.xxx"
name, suffix = file_name.split(".")

date_string = name[-14:]

parsed_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

This will give you the datetime from the filename as a Python datetime object which you can use the greater symbol `>` to compare it against another datetime object.

```
if parsed_date > datetime(2022, 9, 7, 19, 15, 11, 0):
    # copy file
```

Comment: This only makes sense if I'm listing the remote files before I actually copy them, which is not the case

Comment: How would you know what there is to copy if you don't list them first? I think the flow 1) List remote files 2) work out which files need copying 3) copy files makes sense.

Comment: Digging into it, `rsync` seems to be a viable alternative, as I don't really need to list them in the first place, I could just include files using regex. this is probably the way to go